# Release build crash, Swift, Armchair framework, Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, swift, ad-hoc-distribution

I am using Armchair framework (https://github.com/UrbanApps/Armchair) as the app review manager for my app. The app is written in Swift (complies with Swift 1.1) and I am running Xcode 6.2 with base SDK 8.2 and deployment target of 8.0.

I am facing a curious issue while doing a release/ad-hoc build of the app- the app crashes right after getting started. I symbolicated the crash logs and here's what I see-

```
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-05-08 13:01:54.192 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-05-08 13:01:52.013 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      105

    Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001007643d8
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    __TFC8Armchair7ManagerP33_0F5394B43958D8E2A7FE7B1C7DE959CE18defaultReviewTitlefS0_FT_SS Armchair.swift:1566
    __TFC8Armchair7ManagerP33_0F5394B43958D8E2A7FE7B1C7DE959CE18defaultReviewTitlefS0_FT_SS Armchair.swift:695
    __TFC8Armchair7ManagerP33_0F5394B43958D8E2A7FE7B1C7DE959CE15showRatingAlertfS0_FT_T_ Armchair.swift:699
    __dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
    __dispatch_client_callout + 12
    __dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1604
    ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
    ___CFRunLoopRun + 1488
    _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
    _GSEventRunModal + 164
    _UIApplicationMain + 1484
    11  <MyAppName>                 0x0000000100292560 0x1000e8000 + 1746272
    _tlv_get_addr + 176
```

When I run the app on simulator/run directly on the device from Xcode, everything runs perfectly.

Any pointers from anyone?

Comment: Looks like an exception in the Armchair framework. I would contact them directly - perhaps the developers are aware of the issue already? Do you have the Armchair source code? Is there any code relating to defaultReviewTitle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would do is update to the latest Xcode (6.3.1). You will have to scurry around to fix your Swift because of changes in the language. But this version of Swift also fixes a number of memory management bugs that cause crashes in Release builds (and do not show up in Debug builds).

Of course, that might not help if all you've got is the compiled code for this third-party framework.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my code to the latest Xcode (6.3.1) and Swift 1.2 and everything seems to work normal now. I would hence mark your answer as the accepted one since it did guide me in the proper direction.